# Verb for attending a lecture without registering

Tags: single-word-requests

In other words, going to a lecture at university that you didn't pay for.

I clearly remember there was a specific verb for that.

Comment: Lectures at universities are free to students. Do you mean sneak in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "lecture" (I recall that there is a difference between British and American English), but if you attend a class without formally registering or paying for it, in America we typically say that you are "auditing" it.

Reference: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/audit

Comment: This is probably what the OP has in mind, although it should be noted that, at most institutions, auditing is a formally defined status, and the regulations require that somebody who intends to audit a course get a permission to do so, register as such, and pay a fee (albeit a much more modest fee than other students in the same course).

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, you're absolutely right, auditing is often a formal status that requires registration and a fee. It typically doesn't provide a grade or course credit, though it may be noted on a transcript. Practices vary at different institutions. Thank you for noting that!

Comment: There's a question on Academia Stack Exchange (a good site for this sort of query) which goes into more detail on auditing: answers suggest differing practices at different institutions. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/52137/what-does-auditing-a-course-mean

Comment: You may well be correct — I am not an American. But how can I judge without any reference or citation. At the moment your answer does not satisfy SE criteria and I have downvoted it. If you supply supporting authority I will reverse my vote and upvote your answer.

Comment: @David I normally don't provide a reference or citation when it's very easy to confirm. In this case, just about any dictionary will do. Since you requested it, I've added it to the answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: "Monitoring' is another term I recall from my college days in the US.

Comment: Thank you. I have reversed my vote. I do think this is important for several reasons. First and foremost, an answer should be self-contained — the answerer does the work, provides a resource, and gets credit for it. So “It‘s very easy to confirm” doesn’t wash here. When I first joined this list I didn’t think I needed to quote dictionaries until I was told in no uncertain terms that this was expected. Other reasons — the usage is US only, which should be stated, and it is unclear from the question whether this is a licit or illicit activity. A better answer would clarify these points.

Comment: @David The help pages for this site (specifically, at https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) say that "links to external resources are encouraged" but never that they are required (as far as I can see), so I'm surprised that someone indicated that "in no uncertain terms." But perhaps that discussion would more appropriate on meta than here . . . :)

Comment: But think about it. How best will answers fulfill the objectives of this site?

Comment: @David I suppose that we simply disagree about how much effort is required on the part of answerers and how much is reasonable to expect of askers.

Comment: I would look at some of the best examples of answers on this list and consider your position. One other point. It is very easy in one's native language to be convinced that one's own experience of usage is "correct". Actually looking up sources to quote (the OED is good because of its historical listings of usage) has on occasions found me out. English is fluent, and todays "misusage" may actually have been yesterday's standard usage.